# How many boolean functions are possible for n-dimensional input with n-training examples

Tags: boolean-logic

[image]

Can someone please explain why are there 2^9 boolean functions possible for 7 examples?

Comment: `16-7=9` should give you an idea what is happening there.

Comment: @Progman Thank you. I wasn't thinking like that.